# How to remove rows with certain values

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

I want to remove the rows that contain "New York" in city column. I have written the following:

```
     mydata=mydata[(mydata['city'] != ' New York')
```

When I query like below, I do not get any rows back (I checked for different white space variations too)

```
    mydata[(mydata['city'] == ' New York')
```

But when I use extra trees, New York is present in the figure...

1- What could be causing this?
2- How can I remove all variations of New York (like ' New York', 'New York ', 'New York')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and change tested value with no trailing space:

```
mydata=mydata[(mydata['city'].str.strip() != 'New York') ]
```